# The background color of my login screen turned black. How do I change it back to the default?

Tags: login, css

On a couple of 3.4.8 sites I manage, the login screen has changed from blue to black. I have found this code in the index.php file of the admin template (isis).

```
    /* Template color */
    <?php if ($this->params->get('templateColor')) : ?>
    .view-login {
        background: <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor'); ?>;
    }
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Once the page is rendered the html looks like this:

/* Template color */
                .view-login {
            background: #000000;
        }

It's inline, so a style sheet won't override it. I've looked in every file in the template manager and can't figure out where it's getting the black from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->params->get` means there is a parameter in your Template options.

Simply go go:

> Extensions >> Templates >> Isis >> Advanced

Then the color parameter you need to change it "**Nav Bar Colour**"

---

See screenshot below:

[image]